# How to make tableview rows select with already existing values in Array. in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

Model for cell

```
class LangModel{
var name: String?
var id: Int?
var isSelected: Bool?

init(name: String?, id: Int?, isSelected: Bool?) {
    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.isSelected = isSelected
}
}
```

I am adding values to tableview from JSON like below

```
for langData in getuserData?.result?.language ?? []{

   self.langCellArray.append(LangModel(name: langData.language ?? "", id: langData.id ?? 0, isSelected: false))
  }
 tableView.reloadData()
```

with the below code i am able to show tableview when i click `languagesBtn` and select and deselect the tableview rows..

**but here i need is.. if `languageTextField.text` contains languages then if i click languagesBtn then the tableview rows should be selected with languageTextField text**

how to do that

`showPop` showing tableview view with DONE and CANCEL buttons and `languageTextField is inside languagesBtn` in design

```
@IBAction func languagesBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    showPop()
}

@IBAction func cancelBtn(_ sender: Any) {
remove()
}

@IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: Any) {

languageTextField.text = selectedlangArray.joined(separator: ", ")
print("Lang array \(selectedlangArray)")
remove()
tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return langCellArray.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditLangTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell

cell.langLbl.text = langCellArray[indexPath.row].name

let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none

return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell:EditLangTableVIewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell

cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
langCellArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
selectedlangArray.append((cell.langLbl?.text)!)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell:EditLangTableVIewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell
cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

please do help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a property `isSelected` in the model, use it (and declare it as non-optional, there is no *maybe-state*).

**`selectedIndexPaths` as well as extra arrays are not needed at all.** Remove them.

You can even use a struct (the initializer is for free)

```
struct LangModel {
    var name: String?
    var id: Int?
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

In `cellForRowAt` set the accessory view depending on `isSelected`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditLangTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell
    
    let item = langCellArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.langLbl.text = item.name
    cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    
    return cell
}
```

And in `didSelect` toggle `isSelected` and reload only the row. Don't modify the cell directly, tell `cellForRow` to do it by calling `reloadRows(at:with:)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    langCellArray[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) 
}
```

And delete also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell:EditLangTableVIewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: thank you.. i need to add selected row text in textfield so in ur code `didSelectRowAt ` i have added like this `selectedlangArray.append((cell.langLbl?.text)!)`

Comment: here when tableview is coming then check mark is showing but.. i guess the cell is not selecting.. bcz if i select the checkmarked row then checkmark gone and then the cell value coming in textfield.... how to solve this issue

Comment: Don’t get (static) data from the cell, never do that, get it always from the model. `cell.langLbl.text ` is the same as `langCellArray[indexPath.row].name`.  And stop using those extra arrays. `filter` the data source. You get the name of all selected cells with `langCellArray.filter{$0.isSelected}.map(\.name)`. For the visible selection issue set `isSelected` of the cell in `cellForRow` to `isSelected` of the model.

Comment: most of the problem is solved but the issue is
if i add if i add like this `languageTextField.text = langCellArray.filter{$0.isSelected}.map(\.name)` then the error is `Cannot assign value of type '[String?]' to type 'String'`

Comment: i need to show array of languages in textfield with coma separation

Comment: `langCellArray.filter{$0.isSelected}.compactMap(\.name).joined(separator:", ")`

Comment: thank you so much, i have been waiting for this solution from so long.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `tableView.reloadData()`, it clears all of the previous selected indexPath values inside the `UITableView` instance.

One fix to this issue could be to replace following -

```
let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
```

with

```
let rowIsSelected = (langCellArray[indexPath.row].isSelected == true)
```

ALSO -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell: EditLangTableVIewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .none

    langCellArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

In case we want to continue using `UITableView` built in `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to track selected state, we can discard the changes for `rowIsSelected` I explained above.

The fix would be - to reselect all the previously selected index paths manually after the reload like this -

```
tableView.reloadData()

for (index, model) in langCellArray.enumerated() {
    if model.isSelected == true {
        let ip = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        tableView.selectRow(at: ip, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: with this code check mark is showing but the row is not selected.. bcz when i tap on checkmark row then the checkmark gone and row value added to the textfield